# Error: The order by clause is invalid in views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error in SQL Server 14 where I am trying to build a view based on 4 tables

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified

How do I fix the below so I don't get this error?

```
SELECT        dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID],
            case 
            when PS_Proj.[City Name] is not null then  concat(PS_Proj.[City Name], ' ', PS_Proj.[State])
            when PS_Billing.[Location] is not null then max(PS_Billing.[Location])
            when PS_Time.[Labor Location ID] is not null then max(PS_Location.[Labor Location Name])
            else null
            end AS [Location]
FROM        dbo.PS_Location RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Time ON dbo.PS_Location.[Labor Location ID] = dbo.PS_Time.[Labor Location ID] RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Proj ON dbo.PS_Time.[Project ID] = dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Billing ON dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID] = dbo.PS_Billing.[Project ID]
ORDER BY    PS_Billing.[T/S Date], PS_Time.[Date]
```

I'd like for the most recent PS_Billing location to show and if that is null for the most recent PS_Time location to show.

Comment: If you are creating a view the remove the orber by and order the result form the select on view  ,,

Comment: You are trying to CREATE VIEW and you can't apply an ORDER BY when creating a view. You can apply your ORDER BY when selecting from your view though.

Comment: Perhaps `select top 100 %`?

Comment: Even if you could create your view using top 100% or something there is no guarantee that is the order when you select from it. If you want data in a certain order there is one and only one way to ensure that, by using an order by on the select statement.

Comment: @SeanLange - how do I do that without getting this error? I'm new at this so an example would be really helpful

Comment: Take the ORDER BY clause out of your view.

Comment: @SeanLange- I'm getting an error now asking for a GROUP BY Clause - Column 'dbo.PS_Proj.City Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Wrap the concat in another `MAX`

Comment: @SeanLange: Some people trying to be smart don't use 100%, but 99.99999999999999 :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - LOL!!!

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  Have you tried taking `ORDER BY` out of the view?

Answer (score 2):

Create your view without Order By. Remove ORDER BY    PS_Billing.[T/S Date], PS_Time.[Date] And add them to your SELECT.

```
SELECT     
PS_Billing.[T/S Date] AS TsDate, 
PS_Time.[Date] AS Date,
 dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID],
            case 
            when PS_Proj.[City Name] is not null then  concat(PS_Proj.[City Name], ' ', PS_Proj.[State])
            when PS_Billing.[Location] is not null then max(PS_Billing.[Location])
            when PS_Time.[Labor Location ID] is not null then max(PS_Location.[Labor Location Name])
            else null
            end AS [Location]
FROM        dbo.PS_Location RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Time ON dbo.PS_Location.[Labor Location ID] = dbo.PS_Time.[Labor Location ID] RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Proj ON dbo.PS_Time.[Project ID] = dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.PS_Billing ON dbo.PS_Proj.[Project ID] = dbo.PS_Billing.[Project ID]
```

And select from your view with order by line

```
Select FROM YOUR_VIEW_NAME as V
Order By V.TsDate, V.Date
```

Comment: When I do this I get duplicate rows because each project id has 5 to 3000 different dates or T/S Dates. How do I do this without all of the duplicate rows?

Comment: It is a different question and not related to order by error. You should group projects with “group by”

Comment: The reason I wasn't adding [T/S Date] and [Date] was so that I didn't get the additional rows associated with them - make sense? Otherwise the solution doesn't make sense. This isn't the correct answer unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't make sense actually. I didn't change your query, I just took order by out of your view definition. Adding anew field to select doesn't cause duplicate records. Think on the example below.
Id Name Birthday
1  Abc 1-1-2001
2  Abcd 2-2-2002

SELECT Name FROM User where Name ='Abc'
SELECT Name, Birthday FROM User where Name ='Abc'
Both results will have 1 record has Id=1

Answer (score 0):

You have some aggregate data inside your case expression and you don't have a group by. I am making some guesses here. Also, you should get in the habit of using aliases, it makes things a lot simpler. I would also suggest not putting spaces in your column names as it forces you to constantly wrap columns in square brackets.

Something like this should get you close.

```
SELECT p.[Project ID]
    , MAX(case 
        when p.[City Name] is not null then concat(p.[City Name], ' ', p.[State])
        when b.[Location] is not null then b.[Location]
        when t.[Labor Location ID] is not null then l.[Labor Location Name]
        else null
    end) AS [Location]
FROM dbo.PS_Location l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PS_Time t ON l.[Labor Location ID] = t.[Labor Location ID] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PS_Proj  p ON t.[Project ID] = p.[Project ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PS_Billing b ON p.[Project ID] = b.[Project ID]
GROUP BY p.[Project ID]
```

Comment: I added the case statement to the group by and got tons of errors that look like: 'dbo.PS_Proj.City Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If I add everything separately like this: GROUP BY Project ID, City Name, State, Location... I'll get duplicte rows which I'm trying to avoid. How do I do this without the duplicate rows?

Comment: Don't group by the other columns. They are aggregated.

Comment: When I remove the rows that should aggregate, I'm getting errors on City Name, Location and Labor Location ID: is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @TAD I changed up the query a bit but I am mostly guessing since I have no tables to work with.